# Putting command in the background with Fabric does not work on some hosts

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

For testing purposes, I am running the following command, with plain ssh command line tool:

```
ssh user@host "nohup sleep 100 >> /tmp/xxx 2>&1 < /dev/null &"
```

This is working as expected, in all my hosts: a sleep process is created in the background, and the ssh finishes immediately.

I am trying to implement this functionality in python using Fabric. I end up doing a `run` call. This is what the Fabric logging is reporting:

```
[user@host] run: nohup sleep 100 >> /tmp/xxx 2>&1 < /dev/null &
```

Which is exactly what I expect. But if I check the processes which are running in my host, `sleep 100` is not one of them. Worse yet: the problem happens only on some of my hosts.

I also added some more info to show what process has been created, by appending a "\necho $!" to the command to be run by Fabric. This is what was reported:

```
[user@host] run: nohup sleep 100 >> /tmp/xxx 2>&1 < /dev/null &
echo $!
[user@host] out: 30935
```

I am running out of ideas on how to debug this, since Fabric is reporting that the process has been created, but I see no process running in the other end. The syslog reports that an ssh session is being opened and closed:

```
Dec  6 09:12:09 host sshd[2835]: Accepted publickey for user from 67.133.172.14 port 37732 ssh2
Dec  6 09:12:09 host sshd[2838]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user user by (uid=0)
Dec  6 09:12:10 host sshd[2838]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user user
```

Could I somehow increase the amount of logging that the ssh daemon is producing, so that I can see at least what command is being requested via ssh?

I know that Fabric has some issues with running commands in the [background](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.3.3/faq.html#why-can-t-i-run-programs-in-the-background-with-it-makes-fabric-hang), but that does not seem to be my problem. Could there be other issues with Fabric / ssh / background processes?

### EDIT

I have installed `dtach` on all my systems. The version packaged in Ubuntu 8.04 is too old, and does not allow calling `dtach -n` over ssh (problems with terminal), so I had to download and compile the [dtach sources](http://dtach.sourceforge.net/). After doing that, I was able to run my command like this, with Fabric:

[user@host] run: dtach -n /tmp/Y sleep 100 >> /tmp/xxx 2>&1

This is working fine in all hosts. But this does not fit my scenario, because:

- dtach creates two processes: one for dtach itself, another for the process being run.
- I can not get the pid of the process being started

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You are probably bumping into the infamous [**Fabric issue #395**](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/395). The easiet workaround for these problems is to run your task with `pty=False`.

Comment: It looks like you are right. I have added my testing results to the github issue. With `pty=False` the problem disappears, but I still have an uneasy feeling.

Comment: You can follow up on the issue, this looks like an ssh bug, not a fabric one. You can also upvote a helpful answer ;)

Comment: I've encountered the same issue and this solution helps as long as there's no 'with cd('SomeDir')' before running the command. Although that can be simply fixed by prepend dir, still wonder why.

Comment: Like @MartianPuss, this only worked for me once I removed the 'with cd(SomeDir)' command.