# Get the PID of a process started with fabric run command

Tags: python, fabric

How to get the PID of the processes started by the fabric run command.
I want to keep track of the PID, in case I want to kill the process.
Any better way of dealing with this case?

Comment: Assuming you want to run the started process in the background you could append a `echo $!` to your command. This would return someting like `[1] 893`.

Comment: well i realise that, I haven't explained my self properly. I want to catch hold of the PID of the process started by the fabric run on the host machine. e.g, I run " fab -H lin2 lin3 mytask " on lin1. This will ssh to machines lin2 and lin3. I want to get the PID of the mytask process running on lin2 and lin3. I guess I need to re format the answer.

Comment: But fabric will not return from a `run` or `sudo` call until the started process did finish. If you do not start the process as a background process the pid which would be returned by fabric somehow would be the pid of a process which doesn't exists anymore. Therefore your question makes only sense if you want to start a background process and then (and only then) you could use the `echo $!`.

Comment: @tobltrobs... sorry for the delay, and thanks for the input. I tried to find out a way to run the command as a background process by appending &. Basically I did run("mycommand &"), run("echo $!" ). But its not launching the process and didn't gave any pid. I took help from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396987/putting-command-in-the-background-with-fabric-does-not-work-on-some-hosts) question but couldn't grok it completely.

Comment: I can't tell why your `run("mycommand &")` did not work, I would need more informations. But `run("echo $!" )` did not work because this happens in a new ssh session. Every call to `sudo` or `run` will create a new ssh session, which will be closed when the command finishes. To get the pid you have to append the echo $! to the command you want to have the pid from.

Comment: The solution for Piramiko [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872872/get-pid-from-paramiko) tested working flawlessly for fabric.

Answer (score 5):

This should work because the shell opened by the run command is still open when the echo portion of the command is run:

```
run("mycommand & echo $!")
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: This should work because the shell opened by the run command is still open when the echo portion of the command is run.

Comment: Will this work even when mycommand is a long-running process in tmux?